# Should we have OrderId and separate OrderNumber for E-Commerce Website or we can have only field for both?

Tags: database-design, schema, primary-key

I am working on an Online Grocery Store type of website in which I have one order table to store the order details. Here I am having confusion that whether I should have an OrderId (primary key) and separate user-facing OrderNumber or I can only have an OrderNumber as my primary key as the OrderNumber is going to be unique?

Also, I was considering OrderId to be a UUID type. So can I do the reverse of having only OrderId and considering it as User-Facing Id as well?

Comment: What datatype/format do you use for OrderNumber? If it is complex and hence has some string type than synthetiс OrderId as PK is preferred. In terms of improving performance at least. *I was considering OrderId to be a UUID type.* What is the reason? I think that trivial INT will be enough. In terms of improving performance too.

Comment: @AKina I was thinking of using OrderId as UUID because then I won't require OrderNumber anymore as UUID will always be unique. But I doubt whether it is good practice to expose the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either or both, it doesn't really matter much, other than for some minor performance tuning things as Akina points out.

But yes you're allowed to have two fields that are unique, but only one primary key can exist, so you'd have to choose if that will be your OrderId or your OrderNumber, or a composite key that includes both fields.

Typically if the OrderNumber is a numeric data type field and unique then most people would just use this as the primary key, there would be no need for an OrderId (as this would be a column with a redundant purpose). Otherwise if the OrderNumber was something more complex in format, e.g. "124-72-2101-yum" then having a separate field for OrderId as your primary key would probably be a better choice.

The only other thing to consider, is I see you mentioned using UUID for OrderId. If you were to make a UUID field as your primary key (and keep the clustered index on it) there would be performance degradation when trying to JOIN your other tables to it (depending on how big your tables were). You theoretically could make it the primary key without making it the clustered index, and again if your OrderNumber field is of a numeric type then you can make that the clustered index for performance reasons, but at that point you might as well just use OrderNumber as your primary key too and get rid of the OrderId field.

An INT or BIGINT column provide just as much benefits as UUID in regards to being a primary key, but with much better performance. The only benefit UUID carries over them is somewhat global uniqueness which can be useful in certain contexts (like a mobile app that needs to function offline and be consolidated with the main database later on). Though there are ways to achieve this only using INT and BIGINT data types as your primary keys too, it just requires a little more implementation work. But even then my personal preference would be to use INT or BIGINT and put in the little bit of extra work upfront, to not worry about continually trying to optimize performance of my queries later on. And even UUID has a small chance for collisions / producing the same ID twice too (across systems), so it's not perfect.

Comment: The datatype for OrderNumber would be varchar but I am a bit confused about it also as OrderNumber will be user-facing and should be unique. Can you give some idea about generating such numbers as well!!

Comment: @Sunny In a database system, there's typically a concept called IDENTITY which means the column will automatically generate an integer value when a row is inserted. That value is guaranteed to be UNIQUE and 1 greater than the last maximum value (generally speaking).

Comment: yes, but if I take OrderNumber as an identity that will generate an int value every time, I can't directly show these values to the user. I want OrderNumber to be random (eg. of ordernumber from amazon: 402-5048388-9017101)

Comment: @Sunny What benefit do you get from randomizing the Order Number?... anonymity so one user can't look up another user's order by guessing the number?

Comment: Yes exactly. So that any user can't guess the next order number.

Comment: @Sunny Then it's ok to have both, OrderNumber & OrderId. OrderId will be an integer data type identity to ensure 100% uniqueness and best performance for querying, and therefore should be the Primary Key. Your OrderNumber will be a randomly generated ID that is public facing to the Customer and should only be used to look up the Order record to get the OrderId. Any further querying after you have the OrderId should be done against the OrderdId (again for performance reasons). You can create a secondary index on OrderNumber to help performance of that initial lookup for getting to the OrderId.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was talking about. OrderId as int and primary key and a unique user-facing OrderNumber. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I was considering OrderId to be a UUID type [...] and considering it as User-Facing Id as well

Don't. Imagine your user calling customer service and they ask the user: "What's your order number, please?"